# freopen only prints one line when printf prints as much lines as i want (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

So i wanted to print a few lines of GL's Vertex2d coordinates into a file and i used this:

```
{
   //namespace (for cout + cin)
   using namespace std;

   int p; //number of sides

   //body
   double r,d=3/4.0;

   cout << "input side count" <<endl;
   cin >> p;
   cout << "input radius" <<endl;
   cin >> r;

   FILE *fp;

   int i=0;
   double x,y,t;
   while(i<p)
   {
      t=2*M_PI*((double)i/p+d);
      x=cos(t)*r;
      y=sin(t)*r;

      if((fp=freopen("PTRON", "w" ,stdout))==NULL) {
         printf("Cannot open file.\n");
         exit(1);
      }

      printf("glVertex2d(%f, %f);\n",i,x,i,y);

      i++;
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

But it only printed one line to the file wich looked like this;

glVertex2d(-0.406737, -0.913545);

While in console it would print all the lines, like this:

```
glVertex2d(-0.406737, -0.913545);
glVertex2d(0.591057, -0.309017);
glVertex2d(0.587785, 0.80197);
glVertex2d(-0.687785, 0.809017);
etc.
```

Why does it do that? i need all of them to import them later into OpenGL part of the program so it draws the polygon with the desired radius and number of sides

I know that it shouldnt be glVertex2d( 0.0, 0.0 ); but something elese, however i did not get to the point where this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the following lines outside the `while` loop.

```
  if((fp=freopen("PTRON", "w" ,stdout))==NULL) {
     printf("Cannot open file.\n");
     exit(1);
  }
```

I don't know what the behavior of `freopen` is when you use it multiple times in a program.

Use:

```
   if((fp=freopen("PTRON", "w" ,stdout))==NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open file.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   while(i<p)
   {
      t=2*M_PI*((double)i/p+d);
      x=cos(t)*r;
      y=sin(t)*r;

      printf("glVertex2d(%f, %f);\n",i,x,i,y);

      i++;
   }
```